# Troubleshot erronous BIND9 DNS Address entry

Tags: bind

I setup a BIND9 DNS server in the LAN as a backend to Samba4 service.
The network address of my LAN is 192.168.2.0/24 and I statically specify the IP address of DNS server as 192.168.2.144.

Unfortunately, there is another MIC on my DNS server (in fact, the DNS server is a virtual box, the extra MIC is the virtual bridge).
They are in different network, the network address of the virtual bridge is 192.168.122.0/24.

I bind a domain name `dc.foo.bar` to the static address `192.168.2.144` in `/etc/named.conf`.
However, when I query the DNS information with `host -t A dc.foo.bar`, two entries are returned, one is `192.168.2.144` while the other is `192.168.122.1`.

I don't want `dc.foo.bar` binds to `192.168.122.1`, neither do I know how it is added into the DNS service.
How could I trouble shot the problem and remove the erronous DNS address entry?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be curious to find out what your `/etc/named.conf` looks like.

Usually you would first make the DNS server authoritative for `foo.bar` (i.e. create a master zone).

Inside the zone file you would then add an A record for a host called `dc`.

Could you also include the output of `dig @192.168.2.144 +trace dc.foo.bar` and `dig @192.168.2.144 +trace foo.bar`